# syncfusion popup image upload from file of project xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms, popup, syncfusion

I am working on `Xamarin forms` using `synfusion` controls.

I needed a page with image upload in popup page, but image is not uploaded from the project image folder.

After debugging it seems the main problem is the tags and its properties

so please kindly suggest what should I use for the same.

```
<sfPopup:SfPopupLayout x:Name="popupLayout">
    <sfPopup:SfPopupLayout.PopupView>
            <sfPopup:PopupView HeaderTitle="Popup Imagess"
                           AnimationMode="None"
                           AutoSizeMode="None"
                           HeightRequest="{OnPlatform UWP={OnIdiom Phone=250, Tablet=290, Desktop=290}, Android=350, iOS=250}" >

                <sfPopup:PopupView.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <syncfusion:SfListView  x:Name="listView" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,10,10,10"
                               SelectionMode="None" Grid.Row="1"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Gallerynfo}"
                                ItemDoubleTapped="ListView_ItemDoubleTapped_1"
                               ItemSpacing="3">


                        <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="#EEEEEE" Padding="2">

                                            <Grid x:Name="headerGrid" RowSpacing="1">
                                                <Label LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
         Text="photo" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="Fill"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ImageTitle}"
                                   LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                   TextColor="Black" Opacity="0.87"
                                   Margin="16,0,0,0">
                                                </Label>

                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            </Grid>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </syncfusion:SfListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sfPopup:PopupView.ContentTemplate>
        </sfPopup:PopupView>
    </sfPopup:SfPopupLayout.PopupView>
    <sfPopup:SfPopupLayout.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="layout">
            <Button x:Name="clickToShowPopup" Text="ClickToShowPopup" VerticalOptions="Start" 
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Clicked="ClickToShowPopup_Clicked" />
        </StackLayout>
    </sfPopup:SfPopupLayout.Content>
</sfPopup:SfPopupLayout>
```

Comment: please show what have you tried so far?

Comment: kindly see the xmal code.

Comment: What you mean by "but image is not uploaded from the project image"? Are you uploading to API ? What is the error?